# Having multiple var data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, instagram-api

The script below is calling the instagram site of "data1" and prints the `UserCount` into a Spreadsheet. but I want to use different `instagramAccountName`

I'd like to set up 3 more datas.

The `var instagramAccountName = "data1"&&"data2";` isnt working, so what's your suggestions?

```
var sheetName = "Tabellenblatt1";
var instagramAccountName = "data1";

function insertFollowerCount() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(this.sheetName);
  accountdata = getInstagramData(this.instagramAccountName);
  sheet.appendRow([instagramAccountName, Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd"), accountdata.followerCount]);  
 };

function getInstagramData(username) {
  var r = new RegExp('<script type="text\/javascript">' + 
                   '([^{]+?({.*profile_pic_url.*})[^}]+?)' +
                   '<\/script>');
  var url = "https://www.instagram.com/" + username
  var source = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  var jsonStr = source.match(r)[2];
  var data = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
  console.log('data', data);
  var oldVariantOfData = data['entry_data']['ProfilePage'][0];
  console.log('oldVariantOfData', oldVariantOfData);

  return {
    followerCount : oldVariantOfData.graphql.user.edge_followed_by.count,
    followCount : oldVariantOfData.graphql.user.edge_follow.count, 
    mediaCount : oldVariantOfData.graphql.user.edge_owner_to_timeline_media.count
  };  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. First, just reference your global variables by their names, there is no need for `this`.
2. Second, `"data1" && "data2"` equals to "data1 AND data2" (Google Apps Script is a subset of JavaScript), which always stores `true` in your `instagramAccountName` variable.
3. Third, there are a lot of ways to reference multiple account names, but you can write to your `instagramAccountName` variable an `Array` of names `= ['n1','n2']` and then invoke `getInstagramData(username)` using a `for`, `for...of` loop or `forEach` method.

In the end, your function should look like this (btw, `accountdata` should be defined in an outer scope, otherwise you will get a `ReferenceError`):

```
var instagramAccountName = ['data1','data2'];

function insertFollowerCount() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);

  instagramAccountName.forEach(function(username){
    accountdata = getInstagramData(username);
    sheet.appendRow([username, Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 
    "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd"), accountdata.followerCount]); 
  });     
};
```

**References**

1. `forEach` method [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) on MDN

Comment: You are an absolutely HERO! Thank You. But I do have now an issue with the output: instead of printing 'data1' as account name it prints `[Ljava.lang.Object;@2587f384`

Comment: Sorry, forgot to change the reference - the code attempted to write an `Array` of names to the cell :)
Btw, is your `accountdata` a variable defined outside `insertFollowerCount`? If not, please, initialize it with `var accountdata`

Comment: Glad I could help! Take a look at the [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/) when you have time - it will help you better understand how the apps script works